# Could a SELECT harm or interfere with a data insertion script in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, select, insert

This seems like a pretty basic question but one I don't know the answer to.

I wrote a script in PHP that loops through some data and then performs an UPDATE to records in our database. There are roughly some 150,000 records, so the script certainly takes a while to complete.

Could I potentially harm or interfere with the data insertion if I run a basic SELECT statement?

Say...I want to ensure that the script is working properly so if I run a basic SELECT COUNT() to see if it's increasing in real time as the script runs. Is this possible or would it screw something up?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you running the `UPDATE` statements in a transaction?

Comment: If you're using InnoDB, then the answer is no.

Comment: Can you just run an sql command for select * on the table to see if it's updating?

Comment: What database are you using? Also, what version of that database?

Comment: if you are using phpMyAdmin while running a script and you click on browse it shows you the total rows. So if script keeps inserting the number keeps increasing, i dont think it would interfere or harm data insertion.

Answer (score 1):

Generally a `SELECT` call is incapable of "causing harm" provided you're not talking about [SQL injection problems](http://bobby-tables.com/).

The InnoDB engine, which you *should* be using, has what's called [Multi-Version Concurrency Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control) or MVCC for short. It means that until your `UPDATE` statement is finished, or the transaction that the statement is a part of, the `SELECT` will be done against the last consistent database state.

If you're using MyISAM, which is a very bad idea in most production environments due to the limitations of that engine and the way the data is stored without a rollback journal, the `SELECT` call will probably block until the `UPDATE` is applied since it does not support MVCC.